# PostgreSQL, NOT IN clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, analytics

I want to calculate DAU and exclude user that we don't consider "real" (employees, beta testers etc).

It worked fine previously when I wrote the filtering in the query:

```
SELECT 
    count(distinct user_id) AS daily, 
    e.event_timestamp::DATE AS date
FROM 
    "public"."events" AS e
WHERE
   user_id IN (SELECT  
           distinct id
        from
            "user"."user"
        WHERE 
            username IS NOT NULL AND position IS NOT NULL )
GROUP BY date
```

When I try changing it to below, which should give more or less the same count (basically instead of defining the 4000 "real users" I define the 1000 "non-users" I want to exclude). However, this gives me way higher counts. It's like the distinct statement isn't working.

I added the NOT NULL to the subquery but doesn't change the result. Is there something with the NOT IN + subquery that works in another way than the IN clause?

```
SELECT 
    count(distinct e.user_id) AS daily, 
    e.event_timestamp::DATE AS date
FROM 
    "public"."events" AS e
WHERE
   e.user_id NOT IN (SELECT distinct id FROM "public"."non_users" WHERE id IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY 
    date
ORDER BY
    date
```

Comment: It's just an *other* condition, then the previous one. And it may match more records, there's nothing unusual about that. Post the DDL of the tables and some sample data as DML. Explain the semantics of the tables and columns and exactly what you want to query. Include an expected result corresponding to the sample data. Then we might be able to help you to find the right query. (Side note: Try to avoid `IN` with large data sets from a subquery. Use `EXISTS` instead.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  If any of the values in the subquery are `NULL`, then `NOT IN` returns no rows  For this reason, I strongly recommend that you always use `NOT EXISTS` -- it behaves as expected.

You seem to know this, because you are using a `NULL` comparison in the `WHERE`.  So, the difference is probably due to the other condition.  So, include it as well:

```
SELECT count(distinct e.user_id) AS daily, 
       e.event_timestamp::DATE AS date
FROM  "public"."events" e
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM "public"."non_users" nu
                  WHERE e.user_id = nu.id AND
                        nu.position IS NOT NULL
                 )
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date;
```